# Trying to retrieve data from URL and store in a local DB and then append to a listview

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I was trying to retrieve data from URL and store it in a local DB and then appending that data to listview.
I was trying to new so please dont mind if the code have big mistakes or wrong procedure... suggest me how to do it.

my Database class is

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "placesmanager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_PLACES = "places";
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists TABLE_PLACES(name varchar(50),rating varchar(50),icon varchar(50))");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PLACES);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}
//adding contact
public void addContact(PlacesData data) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", data.getName());
    values.put("rating", data.getRating());
    values.put("icon", data.getIcon());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_PLACES, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting All Contacts
public ArrayList<PlacesData> getAllContacts() {
    ArrayList<PlacesData> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_PLACES;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            PlacesData contact = new PlacesData();
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(0));
            contact.setRating(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setIcon(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}
```

and the method of recyclerview that iam appending to Database and trying to retrive it is

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(MyRecycler holder, final int position) {

    DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(activity);
    handler.addContact(new PlacesData(data.get(position).getName(),data.get(position).getRating(),data.get(position).getIcon()));
  //  Log.i("Database",handler+"");

    ArrayList<PlacesData> contacts = handler.getAllContacts();

    for (PlacesData cn : contacts) {
        String log = "Name: "+cn.getName()+" ,Rating: " + cn.getRating() + " ,Icon: " + cn.getIcon();
        Log.i("Name: ", log);
        holder.tvName.setText(cn.getName());
        holder.tvRating.setText(cn.getRating());
        Picasso.with(activity).load(cn.getIcon()).into(holder.imgIcon);
    }
        }
    });
```

Appending the DB data to recyclerview is done, but not in correct way the fields are repeating in view.and in Android Monitor the following  error is showing.

[image]

I am doing this by following some google examples suggest me possible changes.

and finally the output is
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your adapter class like this

```
public class PlacesDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PlacesDataAdapter.Viewholder>
{

    ArrayList<PlacesData> PlacesDatalist;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public PlacesDataAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<PlacesData> PlacesDatalist){
        this.context=context;
        this.surveylist=PlacesDatalist;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }
    @Override
    public Viewholder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
        return new Viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Viewholder holder, int position)
    {
            final PlacesData placedata=surveylist.get(position);

            holder.tvName.setText(placedata.getName());
            holder.tvRating.setText(placedata.getRating());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return PlacesDatalist.size();
    }


}
```

fetching the data from local database,in your activity(Clear the arraylist every time so that value will not repeat in your list means do "contacts.clear" )

```
ArrayList<PlacesData> contacts = handler.getAllContacts();
```

after that just make an object of your adapter class and pass arraylist inside this and do notifydatasetchange.

```
PlacesDataAdapter adapter=new SurveyAdapter(this,contacts);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank u bro i got the solution by some additional changes along with your suggestion

Comment: its my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

Declare an ID in your Database's onCreate. I think that's the problem. Every table must contain a ID (primary key) which is unique for each row.